# What is the simplest way to print a PDF file?

Tags: printing, pdf

There are several ways to use OpenOffice to print a PDF file, but somehow that feels like using a sledgehammer to swat a fly.  So what is the very simplest, lightweight way to print a PDF file without using any heavy-duty machinery?

Comment: Super-duper lightweight: [Print PDF using a shell command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421341/print-pdf-from-command-line-in-linux-similar-to-enscript-2lr)

Comment: You could also use `okular` to open the file, which isn't as light-weight as the command-line, but probably more light-weight than OpenOffice.

Comment: You can use the default pdf viewer installed on your system (e.g. `Evince` in regular Ubuntu), and print the document from there. The shortcut is `ctrl+ P`. https://help.gnome.org/users/evince/stable/printing.html.en

Comment: It is not clear to me, if you want to print a pdf to paper (in which case there is absolutely no reason why you should involve Openoffice) or if you want to convert some file to pdf, in which case we need information about the type of file.

Comment: If you just want to print a file, `lpr file.pdf` (see `man lpr lpq  lpstat`)